# JavaScript/jQuery Class modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the state of a button (using Bootstrap) from active to inactive based on input from the user. In the bigger picture, I am trying to come up with an intuitive way to test input for a form, so that once every field is valid, the submit button can then be pressed for PHP processing on the server side. Here is what I currently have for code:

```
<br>
<label>
    Input: <input type="text" name="sample" class="form-control" id="input" onkeyup="activateButton()" required>
</label>

<br>
<label>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success disabled" id="button">Submit</button>
</label>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function activateButton() {
        "use strict";

        var input = document.getElementById("input").val();
        if (input == "activate") {
            document.getElementById("button").className = "btn btn-success active";
        }

    }
</script>
```

This is, of course within html markup, and so I wanted to get some pointers on how to approach this, since my current setup doesn't seem to work. Thank you!

Comment: btw `document.getElementById("input").val();` should be `document.getElementById("input").value;`

Comment: Thats all it is. That should probably be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `document.getElementById("input").val();` should be `document.getElementById("input").value;`

And Since you have tagged question in jquery too..

```
 function activateButton() {
        "use strict";

        var input =$("#input").val();
        if (input == "activate") {
            $("#button").toggleClass("btn btn-success active");
        }

    }
```

ADDITION(extra info asked by the user):

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
        var d=$(this).val();
        var res = d.test(/your-regex-here/);
        if(res)
        {
              //enable button here
        }
        else
        {
              //disable button here
        }
    });
```

Comment: With this jQuery code, is it possible to format it such that it checks (in real time) the value of the field, and changes the button accordingly?

Comment: Let's say I wanted to test it against a regex pattern, and so if the user entered a valid input, it would allow them to click the button, but if they used backspace, or entered an invalid character it would disable it again. Thanks for your help @Varun !

Comment: @UsmanTahir Check the answer,i have made an addition,which hoepfully is what you want